# Site ASp Net MVC não exibe itens i class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap

Criei um site de e-commerce em Asp Net padrão MVC, ao rodar o site local no Visual Studio pelo ISS ele carrega todos os icones "i class" e o campo de valor que defini como

> segue resultado do Console ao abrir a pagina no ISS: 
>   "Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
>   [Learn More]
>   jquery.js:1
>   TypeError: $.scrollUp is not a function
>   [Learn More]
>   main.js:13:3
>   O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented.
>   jquery.js:5:17117
>   Falha no carregamento do  com a fonte “http://localhost:15742/2872e502bd66452dbb023c224d610830/browserLink”.
>   localhost:5215:433
>   perf_trace {"name": "e2e", "parent": "PageEvents.BIGPIPE_ONLOAD"}
>   wFjNfmdsppO.js:186:2813
>   Source map error: request failed with status 404
>   Resource URL: http://localhost:5215/js/jquery.js
>   Source Map URL: jquery-1.10.2.min.map"

ele exibe o valor corretamente para padrão R$. 
Ao subir o site, percebi que os ícones "i class" ficam sem exibir os desenhos e o campo referente a valor exibe $ apenas. Testei em navegadores diferentes e acontece o mesmo problema. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Posta o codigo de como ficou aplicação,mas voce fez com banco de dados?

Comment: Isso, conecta num banco sql. Não postei o código porque fiquei com duvida do que postar, pois o site eh grande. Vou editar e postar a pagina de _Layout.

Comment: Bom,uma coisa que pode ter ocorrido é você não ter trocado a base do banco de dados la no webconfig mas posta só a parte do código relacionado ao problema

Comment: coloquei um exemplo de trecho e as chamadas de css e java script q tem na pagina de layout.

Comment: Por favor, coloque o resultado do console do navegador ao abrir o site do IIS, provavelmente deu algum erro la

Comment: editei a resposta com o resultado do Console ao abrir a pagina inicial do site no ISS local